# Nodejs - Getting Error in babel loader when i initiate npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Getting this error:

ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react' in C:\Users\username\Deskto
p\reactApp @ multi main

```
module.exports = config; 
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path:'./',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'react',    
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Node version - 4.4.7

npm version - 3.10.5

Babel Loaded globally 
`npm install -g babel`
`npm install -g babel-preset-react`

Comment: How did you go with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the loader to 'babel'

```
module.exports = config; 
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path:'./',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',    
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

This is how mine is setup and it works for me.

**Edit:**

This is my full webpack setup:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    },{
      include: /\.json$/,
      loaders: ["json-loader"]
    },{
      test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

With the following dependencies that relate to babel and webpack (not the full list)

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
  }
```

Comment: Yes. I follow your code, and i got error again. 


ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel' in C:\Users\553150\Deskto
p\reactApp
 @ multi main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.

Comment: Have a look at my dependencies and webpack. Also you should install the dependencies with --save or --save-dev depending whether they are dependencies or devDependencies. You don't need to install them globally.